# How to write a Javascript code for counting the number of forms in Dynamic CRM 2011?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I want to write a Javascript code for counting the number of forms available for a particular user according to the security role in Dynamic CRM 2011.

Comment: If by form you mean `<form>` then just do `document.forms.length`

Comment: Where do you want this code to be executed on?

Comment: I got the code to count and i want to hide all the ribbons if only one form is available,the following code is working in my local system then i imported into Online instance but its failed there
 var countForms = Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.items.get();          if(countForms.length==0)  {       alert("One form");
                    //Hiding the Ribbons 
                    window.top.document.getElementById("crmTopBar").style.display = "none";
                 }
                else
                {
                      alert("Two forms");
                      return true;
                }

Comment: @Hashim: If you feel this question as it stands is answered, accept the answer, but if you have a new question about hiding ribbons based on the number of available forms, ask it as another question. It will help you get the most views and helpful answers.

Answer (score 2):

See [Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.items Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309392.aspx#BKMK_roleFormsGetLength).

```cs
Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.items.getLength();
```

Comment: Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.items.getLength() is working in my local system,but when i deployed into online server its not counting the number of forms

Comment: @Hashim: What is it doing? This feature isn't limited to on-premise deployments (at least the documentation doesn't say so). Is the property `null`, is the `items` collection `null`, etc.?